# After installing cocoa pod existing static library not using libssl.a for tls connection and getting bad access

Tags: c++, ios, ssl, openssl, cocoapods

without cocoa pod app working perfectly, static library using libssl.a and crypto.a for making tls connection, but after installing pod, static library not using libssl.a for tls connection and I end up getting bad excess, I investigate a bit and come to this conclusion that cocoa pod is forcing my static library to not use libssl.a is there any way i can tell my static library to forcefully use libssl.a and crypto.a any every condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution, after installing pod it adds `-objC` in other linker flag which imports all the objective C categories from static libraries, I removed it and my library is successfully using openssl to make tls connection.